# Shell script to slice lines and get the first part

Tags: shell, slice, delimiter

I've a task here to extract the file names from a log file which has about 1000 lines, in the log every line starts with the file name followed by other details, I now want to extract every file name(absolute path, starting from './') from each line and put that in a file. A sample log file has the below data.

```
./plugins-src/rabbitmq-management/src/rabbit_mgmt_wm_overview.erl:1:%%   The contents of this file are subject to the Mozilla Public License
./plugins-src/rabbitmq-management/src/rabbit_mgmt_old_db.erl:1:%%   The contents of this file are subject to the Mozilla Public License
./plugins-src/rabbitmq-management/src/rabbit_mgmt_wm_exchange.erl:1:%%   The contents of this file are subject to the Mozilla Public License
./plugins-src/rabbitmq-management/src/rabbit_mgmt_wm_channel.erl:1:%%   The contents of this file are subject to the Mozilla Public License
./plugins-src/rabbitmq-management/src/rabbit_mgmt_wm_vhosts.erl:1:%%   The contents of this file are subject to the Mozilla Public License
./plugins-src/rabbitmq-management/src/rabbit_mgmt_wm_permission.erl:1:%%   The contents of this file are subject to the Mozilla Public License
./plugins-src/rabbitmq-management/src/rabbit_mgmt_util.erl:1:%%   The contents of this file are subject to the Mozilla Public License
./plugins-src/rabbitmq-management/src/rabbit_mgmt_wm_queue_purge.erl:1:%%   The contents of this file are subject to the Mozilla Public License
./plugins-src/rabbitmq-management/src/rabbit_mgmt_format.erl:1:%%   The contents of this file are subject to the Mozilla Public License
./plugins-src/rabbitmq-management/src/rabbit_mgmt_wm_exchanges.erl:1:%%   The contents of this file are subject to the Mozilla Public License
./plugins-src/rabbitmq-management/src/rabbit_mgmt_wm_bindings.erl:1:%%   The contents of this file are subject to the Mozilla Public License
./plugins-src/rabbitmq-management/src/rabbit_mgmt_wm_definitions.erl:1:%%   The contents of this file are subject to the Mozilla Public License
./plugins-src/rabbitmq-management/src/rabbit_mgmt_wm_queue_get.erl:1:%%   The contents of this file are subject to the Mozilla Public License
./plugins-src/rabbitmq-federation-management/src/rabbit_federation_mgmt.erl:1:%%  The contents of this file are subject to the Mozilla Public License
./plugins-src/rabbitmq-mqtt/src/rabbit_mqtt_processor.erl:1:%% The contents of this file are subject to the Mozilla Public License
./plugins-src/rabbitmq-mqtt/src/rabbit_mqtt_util.erl:1:%% The contents of this file are subject to the Mozilla Public License
./plugins-src/rabbitmq-mqtt/src/rabbit_mqtt_collector.erl:1:%% The contents of this file are subject to the Mozilla Public License
./plugins-src/rabbitmq-mqtt/src/rabbit_mqtt_frame.erl:1:%% The contents of this file are subject to the Mozilla Public License
./plugins-src/rabbitmq-mqtt/src/rabbit_mqtt_sup.erl:1:%% The contents of this file are subject to the Mozilla Public License
./plugins-src/rabbitmq-mqtt/src/rabbit_mqtt.erl:1:%% The contents of this file are subject to the Mozilla Public License
```

there is a colon(:) which can be used as a delimiter that exactly ends the file name in each line, but I've no expertise in shell script to slice it and extract the file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 awk -F':' '{print $1}' filename.log

 # OR 

 cut -d':' -f1 filename.log
```

Comment: Glad to hear that, if it helped then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another avenue using bash would be:

```
while read -r line; do echo "${line%%:*}"; done <filename
```

It uses *parameter expansion with substring removal* which is a set of builtin character handling routines. Basically:

```
var="123:456:789"
echo "${var#*:}"   # 456:789  remove from left to 1st occurrence of ':'
echo "${var%:*}"   # 123:456  remove from right to 1st occurrence of ':'
echo "${var##*:}"  # 789  remove from left to last occurrence of ':'
echo "${var%%:*}"  # 123  remove from right to last occurrence of ':'
```

(**note:** the position of the wildcard in the expansions)

They can even be nested as well.